# How to use Custom Log Configuration - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a typical Spring Boot application like [this](https://github.com/scratches/spring-boot-sample-gae), how do we configure it to use a "custom" log configuration?

For example, in the current environment that my app runs, logback is causing error, how can I use other logging for example:

```
[INFO] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.io.FileOutputStream is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.    
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:100)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:58)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:181)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:122)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:98)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:92)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:58)
```

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485059/spring-boot-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-with-application-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot configures Logback by default, and you use standard configuration--just have a `logback.xml` or `logback.groovy` available as a classpath resource at runtime. In the GAE case, you'll need to configure the logger to use GAE-approved output targets.