# 404 Exception not handled in Spring ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, error-handling

I have a simple Spring MVC application in which I want to handle all the unmapped urls using `@ControllerAdvice`.
Here is the controller:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerController {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handle404() {
        return "exceptions/404page";
    }
}
```

Still, every time get Whitelabel Error Page.

I tried using `RuntimeException.class`, `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` and extending the class with `NoHandlerFoundException` but no use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To make it work, you need to set `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound` property on DispecherServlet. You can do that with:

```
spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound=true
```

in `application.properties` file, otherwise the requests will always be forwarded to the default servlet and NoHandlerFoundException would ever be thrown.

The problem is, even with this configuration, it doesn't work. From the documentation:

> Note that if
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler is
>   used, then requests will always be forwarded to the default servlet
>   and NoHandlerFoundException would never be thrown in that case.

Because Spring Boot uses by default the `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler` you'll have to override this using your own `WebMvcConfigurer`:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        // Do nothing instead of configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

Of course, the above class might be more complicated in your case.

Comment: Using spring boot 2.0.2.RELEASE this solution didn't work. Had to write a ErrorController 
 as in the answer by zwlxt

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do so is `ErrorController`

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public ModelAndView errorHandler(HttpServletRequest req) {
        // Get status code to determine which view should be returned
        Object statusCode = req.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);
        // In this case, status code will be shown in a view
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("error_default");
        mav.addObject("code", statusCode.toString());
        return mav;
    }

    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below line in **application.properties**

spring.mvc.throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound=true

and **@EnableWebMvc** with **@ControllerAdvice**,
Note: add @Override over handleNoHandlerFoundException method
this worked for me!

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
            HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse();
        response.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
        response.setMessage(ApplicationErrorCodes.NO_HANDLER_FOUND.getErrorMessage());
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        response.setErrorCode(ApplicationErrorCodes.NO_HANDLER_FOUND.getErrorCode());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```