# Spring @ControllerAdvice not applied when packageName or assignableTypes is specified

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

A sample project demonstrating the issue can be found at: https://github.com/dirkbolte/javaexceptionhandlertest

I have a controller which is declared to produce JSON content:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "exception", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

The corresponding controller advice should map any exception to a `BAD_REQUEST` :

```java
@RestControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler {
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public void exceptionhandler() {
    }
}
```

I test that a call with a wrong `accept` header results in the correct error response code (as `procudes` specifies something different):

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class TestControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/exception")
                                  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
        ).andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

The code above "fails successfully" :-) . In my production code I want to limit the controller advice to a certain controller (alternatively to a certain package), thus I specified `assignableTypes` on `@ControllerAdvice`: `@RestControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = TestController.class)` . Now the test fails as the exception handler isn't called anymore. Same happens when specifying `basePackages` or `basePackageClasses` - or when using an interface.

The version on GitHub shows the test failure, so I hope it is easy to reproduce.

How can I use a ControllerAdvice explicitly for one or more Controller?

Comment: If I understand correctly , since the URL cannot be mapped to any controller method it will result in a 404 and will not be intercepted by the ControllerAdvice. Please go through this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54116245/4214241) and it answer to see if it helps

Comment: Frankly your comment helped me more than the linked answer :-) Looks like everything specified on the method signature (like the HTTP method, consumes, produces) results in the URL to not be found. The exception therefore is not thrown by the controller and thus `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#getExceptionHandlerMethod` will be called with `handlerMethod = null` . The controller advice works fine when the controller itself throws the exception. Can you add your comment as answer? I might add some more details to it then.

Comment: Added as answer. When additional metadata is configured for the method and if the request contains the same , it will get mapped to the controller method. You may please try out that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requested URL will not get mapped to any Controller method here. This would result in a Status `406` error (due to the specified accept type). Since no exception is thrown from the Controller methods the ControllerAdvice would not be invoked.

On dispatcher level, `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#getExceptionHandlerMethod` will be called with `handlerMethod = null` which is why only generic controller advices are applied.

The ControllerAdvice would work here, if the request contains additional metadata that the controller method is configured for and/or an exception is thrown from within that method.