# Spring boot rest: issue with json

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

My spring boot rest application has a controller with the below method. It uses hibernate internally to get data from Oracle DB. My issue is that, when I invoke this service, it returns a HTTP ERROR 500. But there aren't any errors logged anywhere and the debug log in the below code prints the entire Job object without any issues. I debugged and saw that the job object is returning as well.
 I doubt some data is causing issue when converting the Job object to json, but how do I find which field is causing the issue ? 
Is there a way to log issues occuring during the json conversion ?

```
@GetMapping(params = {"jobId"})
  @ResponseBody
  public Job findById(long jobId) {
    Job job = jobHistoryService.findById(jobId);
    log.debug(job.toString());
    return job;
  }
```

Comment: @Deadpool This page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20488306/839979

Comment: write a unit test with mockmvc and print the response out. you should be able to see the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the advice in comment and set log level in `applicaion.yml` to `info` and it printed out the error. The error printed out was this.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor
```

Searched stack overflow and found this solution of adding the below to entites and it worked like a charm.Thanks guys !

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
```

[stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24994440/no-serializer-found-for-class-org-hibernate-proxy-pojo-javassist-javassist)