# Run spring app with --debug doesn't affect my loggers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j

```
private static final Logger myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("NAME");
```

I have a couple of loggers created like the example above, the thing is, when I run my Spring app with `--debug`, `myLogger.debug("something")` isn't logged, only spring default/internal loggers acctually make use of the `--debug` args.

How can I make my loggers also use `--<level>` args?

Comment: whether this your `Logger` definition.
`private static final Logger myLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("NAME");`

Comment: Where? It is on the main class.

Comment: Change your logger definition to this.

`private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(YourClassName.class);`

Comment: Still, no debug logs.

Comment: Did you added any properties for logger in your application.properties file

Comment: No, application.properties is empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206561/discussion-between-gnana-jeyam95-and-1nt3rn3t).

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485059/spring-boot-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-with-application-properties/20488306

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. It is not possible to make the other loggers use —debug or any other level.

From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output),

> The default log configuration echoes messages to the console as they
>   are written. By default, ERROR-level, WARN-level, and INFO-level
>   messages are logged. You can also enable a “debug” mode by starting
>   your application with a --debug flag.
>
> $ java -jar myapp.jar --debug
>
> [Note] You can also specify debug=true
>   in your application.properties.
>
> When the debug mode is enabled, a selection of core loggers (embedded
>   container, Hibernate, and Spring Boot) are configured to output more
>   information. Enabling the debug mode does not configure your
>   application to log all messages with DEBUG level.
>
> Alternatively, you can enable a “trace” mode by starting your
>   application with a --trace flag (or trace=true in your
>   application.properties). Doing so enables trace logging for a
>   selection of core loggers (embedded container, Hibernate schema
>   generation, and the whole Spring portfolio).

However you can use below key value to log all debug messages in application properties file

```
logging.level.root=debug
```

More on the implementation here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/logging/LoggingApplicationListener.java

Answer (score 0):

Hi Following is a sample logback.xml, to be placed in the resource folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <logger name="<PACKAGE ON WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO ENABLE DEBUGGING (EXAMPLE: com.mypackage)>" level="DEBUG" />
   <root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="DAILY_ROLLING" />
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

Change `<PACKAGE ON WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO ENABLE DEBUGGING (EXAMPLE: com.mypackage))>`
with your own package on which you would like to enable DEBUG.

Alternatively, if you would like to enable root level on all the packages replace `<root level="ERROR" >` with `<root level="DEBUG" >`. And it will print debug messages of all the code even if it's printed in dependencies. Also, you can remove `<logger name="<PACKAGE ON WHICH YOU WOULD LIKE TO ENABLE DEBUGGING (EXAMPLE: com.mypackage)>" level="debug" />` if the log level of your package is the same as root level.