# Tomcat server not starting in spring boot web app in docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, tomcat

**Problem Description:**
I am encountering difficulties while attempting to run my Spring Boot web application with PostgreSQL in a Docker container. The main issue revolves around the embedded Tomcat server not starting as expected. Strangely, the Docker container exits with a status code of 0, suggesting that the main process (the Spring Boot application) has concluded successfully or terminated unexpectedly.

**Troubleshooting Steps Taken:**

I carefully examined the logs generated by my Spring Boot application to identify any error messages or exceptions that might shed light on why Tomcat is failing to start.

After the container exits, I checked its logs using the docker logs command. My goal was to look for any unusual behavior or error messages that might explain the premature termination.

I revisited my Dockerfile and Docker Compose configurations to ensure they are appropriately set up for running a Spring Boot application. This involved checking dependencies, entry point specifications, and other relevant configurations.

Confirming that my Spring Boot application can establish a successful connection to the PostgreSQL database was crucial. I double-checked the database URL, credentials, and driver class configurations specified in my application.properties.

In an effort to prevent premature container shutdowns, I explored the option of implementing health checks within my application. This involves ensuring that the application is in a healthy state before the container is considered ready.

I am reaching out for assistance to understand why Tomcat is failing to start in my Docker container and why the container is exiting with a status code of 0. If anyone has experienced similar issues or has insights into troubleshooting Spring Boot applications in Docker, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.
**build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}
bootJar{
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
apply plugin: 'java'

springBoot {
    mainClass = 'com.example.fcs.FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication'
    buildInfo()
}
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.example.fcs.FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication'
    }

    archiveFileName = 'app.jar'
    
    destinationDirectory.set(file('src/main/docker'))

    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**docker-compose file:**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 11111111Aa
      POSTGRES_DB: feedback
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/feedback
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: postgres
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: 11111111Aa

volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM openjdk:19
VOLUME /tmp
EXPOSE 8080
ARG JAR_FILE=/*.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
CMD ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
#or entrypoint idk
```

**Main class:**

```
package com.example.fcs;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Logs:**

```
app-1       |  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.0)
app-1       |
app-1       | 16:48:21.928 [main] INFO com.example.fcs.FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication -- Starting FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication using Java 19 with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
app-1       | 16:48:21.941 [main] INFO com.example.fcs.FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication -- No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
app-1       | 16:48:22.942 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
app-1       | 16:48:23.022 [main] INFO org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate -- Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 70 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
app-1       | 16:48:23.484 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Starting...
app-1       | 16:48:23.722 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool -- HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@4a34e9f
app-1       | 16:48:23.724 [main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
app-1       | 16:48:23.778 [main] INFO org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper -- HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
app-1       | 16:48:23.851 [main] INFO org.hibernate.Version -- HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version [WORKING]
app-1       | 16:48:23.900 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator -- HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
app-1       | 16:48:24.136 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo -- No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
app-1       | 16:48:25.238 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator -- HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
app-1       | 16:48:25.243 [main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'        
app-1       | 16:48:25.918 [main] INFO com.example.fcs.FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication -- Started FeedbackCollectionSystemApplication in 4.361 seconds (process running for 4.706)
app-1       | 16:48:25.926 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean -- Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
app-1       | 16:48:25.930 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
app-1       | 16:48:25.936 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource -- HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
app-1 exited with code 0
```

Maybe I have to run tomcat as a seperate container, please, help!

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can enable debug logs of spring? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485059/spring-boot-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-with-application-properties seems the Db connetion is not correct/ not initializing and that is why HikariPool is shutting down. are you testing it locally? why dont you? install docker locally

Comment: what command do you give to start composer?

Comment: docker-compose up --build

Comment: The app runs perfectly when running from intelliJ

Comment: Does it run if you run it with `docker-compose up -d`?

Comment: You don't need to include tomcat because spring-boot-starter-web comes per default with tomcat.

Comment: With your configuration I managed to reproduce your starting behaviour through IntelliJ and the same crashing behaviour through docker-compose. I suspect that the packaging is flawed. Because running the jar directly via `java -jar app.jar` does not run properly.

Comment: Try the spring boot packaging task [bootJar](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable.jars)

Comment: app.jar doesn't run properly by itself beacuse of datasource url, when running with docker-compose it should have postgres:5432, but by itself it should have localhost:5432, thats why. When running with docker-compose, it connects to database perfectly, which doesnt happen when running just app.jar

Comment: tried -d, unfortunately doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify a `depends_on` with proper health checks, docker-compose will start both services simultaneously. When the Postgres container takes more time to start than the app, the app will crash.

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 11111111Aa
      POSTGRES_DB: feedback
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "sh -c 'pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d ${POSTGRES_DB}'"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 3

  app:
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

**Note:** `depends_on` and `healthcheck` require at least docker-compose V2.

A quick fix could be to add a `restart: always` to your app, then it will restart after it has crashed a couple of times until the Postgres container allows the application to successfully connect with it. This solution will pollute your logs, I'd rather use health checks.

```yaml
app:
  restart: always
```

Comment: App starts after postgres, promlem is that it just shuts down after starting without any error, I surmise it is because of tomcat server not starting, so I am trying to fix this issue

Comment: Why not add the depends on and restart and test?

Comment: @tgkprog `restart: always` gives you robustness but might obfuscate a misbehaving service. I would do both if my monitoring would notify me of said faulty service.

Comment: Unfortunately, it changes nothing.