# Changing the default spring "Started" message level from INFO to WARN

Tags: xml, spring-boot, logging

Is it possible to display the "Started SpringApp in 9.708 seconds (JVM running for 38.99)", with a WARN level log instead of an INFO level? If not, I want to make the message stand out so it can be differentiated quickly in Kibana logs

I tried configuring the logback-spring.xml but that does nothing to said message

Comment: No it is not, why would you want to change that ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer ([Spring Boot: How can I set the logging level with application.properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485059/spring-boot-how-can-i-set-the-logging-level-with-application-properties)) you can choose the level of logging (also of some packages/components) in the application.properties like this:

```
logging.level.root=warn
```

You can adjust this so that "Started SpringApp in 9.708 seconds (JVM running for 38.99)" will be displayed as you wish with WARN level. Check which package/component from Spring Boot is logging this message then do the required modifications.
Let me know if it helped.